# Tick marks not visible in my filled contour

Tags: pgfplots

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    colormap/jet,
    x=2.25 cm,
    y=4.5 cm,
    z=0 cm,
 ]
    \addplot3[
    shader=interp,
    contour filled = {number=200,labels={false}}
    ] file {cont.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, the axis tick marks are not displayed. What did I do wrong?

Here's the data for the plot:

```
0   0   0.58685
0.13793 0   0.059563
0.27586 0   0.47212
0.41379 0   0.54384
0.55172 0   0.18857
0.68966 0   0.27536
0.82759 0   0.53887
0.96552 0   0.47654
1.1034  0   0.16292
1.2414  0   0.21783
1.3793  0   0.4829
1.5172  0   0.53014
1.6552  0   0.36113
1.7931  0   0.060493
1.931   0   0.25274
2.069   0   0.47133
2.2069  0   0.53321
2.3448  0   0.43181
2.4828  0   0.20861
2.6207  0   0.066319
2.7586  0   0.31776
2.8966  0   0.48513
3.0345  0   0.5347
3.1724  0   0.46399
3.3103  0   0.28815
3.4483  0   0.073588
3.5862  0   0.48028
3.7241  0   0.56752
3.8621  0   0.10582
4   0   0.52561

0   0.034483    0.58429
0.13793 0.034483    0.059293
0.27586 0.034483    0.47007
0.41379 0.034483    0.54148
0.55172 0.034483    0.18776
0.68966 0.034483    0.27415
0.82759 0.034483    0.53652
0.96552 0.034483    0.47447
1.1034  0.034483    0.16221
1.2414  0.034483    0.21689
1.3793  0.034483    0.48079
1.5172  0.034483    0.52783
1.6552  0.034483    0.35956
1.7931  0.034483    0.06023
1.931   0.034483    0.25163
2.069   0.034483    0.46928
2.2069  0.034483    0.53089
2.3448  0.034483    0.42993
2.4828  0.034483    0.2077
2.6207  0.034483    0.06603
2.7586  0.034483    0.31637
2.8966  0.034483    0.48302
3.0345  0.034483    0.53237
3.1724  0.034483    0.46197
3.3103  0.034483    0.28689
3.4483  0.034483    0.073271
3.5862  0.034483    0.47819
3.7241  0.034483    0.56504
3.8621  0.034483    0.10532
4   0.034483    0.52342

0   0.068966    0.57662
0.13793 0.068966    0.058488
0.27586 0.068966    0.46395
0.41379 0.068966    0.53442
0.55172 0.068966    0.18532
0.68966 0.068966    0.27056
0.82759 0.068966    0.5295
0.96552 0.068966    0.46826
1.1034  0.068966    0.16008
1.2414  0.068966    0.21405
1.3793  0.068966    0.47451
1.5172  0.068966    0.52094
1.6552  0.068966    0.35486
1.7931  0.068966    0.059444
1.931   0.068966    0.24834
2.069   0.068966    0.46315
2.2069  0.068966    0.52395
2.3448  0.068966    0.42431
2.4828  0.068966    0.20499
2.6207  0.068966    0.065167
2.7586  0.068966    0.31224
2.8966  0.068966    0.4767
3.0345  0.068966    0.52541
3.1724  0.068966    0.45593
3.3103  0.068966    0.28313
3.4483  0.068966    0.072325
3.5862  0.068966    0.47194
3.7241  0.068966    0.55763
3.8621  0.068966    0.10383
4   0.068966    0.51686

0   0.10345 0.56395
0.13793 0.10345 0.057164
0.27586 0.10345 0.45385
0.41379 0.10345 0.52278
0.55172 0.10345 0.18131
0.68966 0.10345 0.26462
0.82759 0.10345 0.51792
0.96552 0.10345 0.45802
1.1034  0.10345 0.15658
1.2414  0.10345 0.20938
1.3793  0.10345 0.46414
1.5172  0.10345 0.50956
1.6552  0.10345 0.34711
1.7931  0.10345 0.058148
1.931   0.10345 0.24292
2.069   0.10345 0.45303
2.2069  0.10345 0.5125
2.3448  0.10345 0.41503
2.4828  0.10345 0.20051
2.6207  0.10345 0.063744
2.7586  0.10345 0.30541
2.8966  0.10345 0.46628
3.0345  0.10345 0.51392
3.1724  0.10345 0.44595
3.3103  0.10345 0.27693
3.4483  0.10345 0.070764
3.5862  0.10345 0.46163
3.7241  0.10345 0.5454
3.8621  0.10345 0.10139
4   0.10345 0.50599

0   0.13793 0.54643
0.13793 0.13793 0.055336
0.27586 0.13793 0.43988
0.41379 0.13793 0.50667
0.55172 0.13793 0.17575
0.68966 0.13793 0.25641
0.82759 0.13793 0.50189
0.96552 0.13793 0.44386
1.1034  0.13793 0.15174
1.2414  0.13793 0.20291
1.3793  0.13793 0.4498
1.5172  0.13793 0.49381
1.6552  0.13793 0.33639
1.7931  0.13793 0.056355
1.931   0.13793 0.23541
2.069   0.13793 0.43903
2.2069  0.13793 0.49666
2.3448  0.13793 0.40221
2.4828  0.13793 0.19431
2.6207  0.13793 0.061775
2.7586  0.13793 0.29597
2.8966  0.13793 0.45186
3.0345  0.13793 0.49802
3.1724  0.13793 0.43215
3.3103  0.13793 0.26835
3.4483  0.13793 0.068604
3.5862  0.13793 0.44738
3.7241  0.13793 0.52849
3.8621  0.13793 0.098048
4   0.13793 0.4909

0   0.17241 0.52433
0.13793 0.17241 0.053037
0.27586 0.17241 0.42223
0.41379 0.17241 0.48633
0.55172 0.17241 0.16872
0.68966 0.17241 0.24605
0.82759 0.17241 0.48166
0.96552 0.17241 0.42598
1.1034  0.17241 0.14563
1.2414  0.17241 0.19474
1.3793  0.17241 0.43169
1.5172  0.17241 0.47393
1.6552  0.17241 0.32285
1.7931  0.17241 0.05409
1.931   0.17241 0.22593
2.069   0.17241 0.42135
2.2069  0.17241 0.47666
2.3448  0.17241 0.38601
2.4828  0.17241 0.18648
2.6207  0.17241 0.059288
2.7586  0.17241 0.28405
2.8966  0.17241 0.43366
3.0345  0.17241 0.47795
3.1724  0.17241 0.41472
3.3103  0.17241 0.25751
3.4483  0.17241 0.065876
3.5862  0.17241 0.42938
3.7241  0.17241 0.50715
3.8621  0.17241 0.093859
4   0.17241 0.47175

0   0.2069  0.49795
0.13793 0.2069  0.050303
0.27586 0.2069  0.40113
0.41379 0.2069  0.46202
0.55172 0.2069  0.16032
0.68966 0.2069  0.23368
0.82759 0.2069  0.45749
0.96552 0.2069  0.40462
1.1034  0.2069  0.13833
1.2414  0.2069  0.18498
1.3793  0.2069  0.41006
1.5172  0.2069  0.45019
1.6552  0.2069  0.30668
1.7931  0.2069  0.051385
1.931   0.2069  0.2146
2.069   0.2069  0.40023
2.2069  0.2069  0.45277
2.3448  0.2069  0.36666
2.4828  0.2069  0.17713
2.6207  0.2069  0.056319
2.7586  0.2069  0.26981
2.8966  0.2069  0.41191
3.0345  0.2069  0.45398
3.1724  0.2069  0.39391
3.3103  0.2069  0.24457
3.4483  0.2069  0.062616
3.5862  0.2069  0.40788
3.7241  0.2069  0.48168
3.8621  0.2069  0.088909
4   0.2069  0.44875

0   0.24138 0.46761
0.13793 0.24138 0.047172
0.27586 0.24138 0.37684
0.41379 0.24138 0.43403
0.55172 0.24138 0.15065
0.68966 0.24138 0.21943
0.82759 0.24138 0.42968
0.96552 0.24138 0.38003
1.1034  0.24138 0.12992
1.2414  0.24138 0.17375
1.3793  0.24138 0.38516
1.5172  0.24138 0.42286
1.6552  0.24138 0.28806
1.7931  0.24138 0.048271
1.931   0.24138 0.20157
2.069   0.24138 0.37593
2.2069  0.24138 0.42528
2.3448  0.24138 0.34439
2.4828  0.24138 0.16637
2.6207  0.24138 0.052901
2.7586  0.24138 0.25342
2.8966  0.24138 0.38689
3.0345  0.24138 0.42639
3.1724  0.24138 0.36996
3.3103  0.24138 0.22968
3.4483  0.24138 0.058863
3.5862  0.24138 0.38313
3.7241  0.24138 0.45238
3.8621  0.24138 0.083279
4   0.24138 0.42211

0   0.27586 0.43371
0.13793 0.27586 0.04369
0.27586 0.27586 0.34967
0.41379 0.27586 0.40273
0.55172 0.27586 0.13983
0.68966 0.27586 0.20352
0.82759 0.27586 0.39858
0.96552 0.27586 0.35254
1.1034  0.27586 0.12053
1.2414  0.27586 0.16118
1.3793  0.27586 0.35732
1.5172  0.27586 0.3923
1.6552  0.27586 0.26725
1.7931  0.27586 0.044789
1.931   0.27586 0.18699
2.069   0.27586 0.34875
2.2069  0.27586 0.39453
2.3448  0.27586 0.3195
2.4828  0.27586 0.15434
2.6207  0.27586 0.04908
2.7586  0.27586 0.2351
2.8966  0.27586 0.35891
3.0345  0.27586 0.39554
3.1724  0.27586 0.34318
3.3103  0.27586 0.21304
3.4483  0.27586 0.054664
3.5862  0.27586 0.35547
3.7241  0.27586 0.41964
3.8621  0.27586 0.077057
4   0.27586 0.39213

0   0.31034 0.39671
0.13793 0.31034 0.039907
0.27586 0.31034 0.31997
0.41379 0.31034 0.36853
0.55172 0.31034 0.12801
0.68966 0.31034 0.18614
0.82759 0.31034 0.36463
0.96552 0.31034 0.32253
1.1034  0.31034 0.11027
1.2414  0.31034 0.14747
1.3793  0.31034 0.32692
1.5172  0.31034 0.35892
1.6552  0.31034 0.24451
1.7931  0.31034 0.040986
1.931   0.31034 0.17108
2.069   0.31034 0.31907
2.2069  0.31034 0.36096
2.3448  0.31034 0.2923
2.4828  0.31034 0.1412
2.6207  0.31034 0.044908
2.7586  0.31034 0.21509
2.8966  0.31034 0.32835
3.0345  0.31034 0.36185
3.1724  0.31034 0.31393
3.3103  0.31034 0.19486
3.4483  0.31034 0.050075
3.5862  0.31034 0.32526
3.7241  0.31034 0.3839
3.8621  0.31034 0.070338
4   0.31034 0.35921

0   0.34483 0.3571
0.13793 0.34483 0.035875
0.27586 0.34483 0.28813
0.41379 0.34483 0.33186
0.55172 0.34483 0.11532
0.68966 0.34483 0.16752
0.82759 0.34483 0.32824
0.96552 0.34483 0.29036
1.1034  0.34483 0.099278
1.2414  0.34483 0.13276
1.3793  0.34483 0.29432
1.5172  0.34483 0.32314
1.6552  0.34483 0.22015
1.7931  0.34483 0.036909
1.931   0.34483 0.15402
2.069   0.34483 0.28726
2.2069  0.34483 0.32497
2.3448  0.34483 0.26315
2.4828  0.34483 0.12712
2.6207  0.34483 0.040435
2.7586  0.34483 0.19364
2.8966  0.34483 0.29559
3.0345  0.34483 0.32574
3.1724  0.34483 0.28258
3.3103  0.34483 0.17537
3.4483  0.34483 0.045154
3.5862  0.34483 0.29288
3.7241  0.34483 0.34562
3.8621  0.34483 0.063215
4   0.34483 0.32371

0   0.37931 0.31535
0.13793 0.37931 0.031647
0.27586 0.37931 0.25453
0.41379 0.37931 0.29317
0.55172 0.37931 0.10193
0.68966 0.37931 0.14789
0.82759 0.37931 0.28986
0.96552 0.37931 0.25643
1.1034  0.37931 0.087684
1.2414  0.37931 0.11725
1.3793  0.37931 0.25994
1.5172  0.37931 0.2854
1.6552  0.37931 0.19444
1.7931  0.37931 0.032608
1.931   0.37931 0.13602
2.069   0.37931 0.2537
2.2069  0.37931 0.28701
2.3448  0.37931 0.23241
2.4828  0.37931 0.11226
2.6207  0.37931 0.035719
2.7586  0.37931 0.17102
2.8966  0.37931 0.26105
3.0345  0.37931 0.28765
3.1724  0.37931 0.24952
3.3103  0.37931 0.15482
3.4483  0.37931 0.039958
3.5862  0.37931 0.25873
3.7241  0.37931 0.30527
3.8621  0.37931 0.055779
4   0.37931 0.28607

0   0.41379 0.27201
0.13793 0.41379 0.027276
0.27586 0.41379 0.21961
0.41379 0.41379 0.25296
0.55172 0.41379 0.088003
0.68966 0.41379 0.12751
0.82759 0.41379 0.24999
0.96552 0.41379 0.22118
1.1034  0.41379 0.075643
1.2414  0.41379 0.10113
1.3793  0.41379 0.22423
1.5172  0.41379 0.2462
1.6552  0.41379 0.16774
1.7931  0.41379 0.028139
1.931   0.41379 0.11733
2.069   0.41379 0.21884
2.2069  0.41379 0.24757
2.3448  0.41379 0.20047
2.4828  0.41379 0.096825
2.6207  0.41379 0.030819
2.7586  0.41379 0.14752
2.8966  0.41379 0.22516
3.0345  0.41379 0.24809
3.1724  0.41379 0.21518
3.3103  0.41379 0.13348
3.4483  0.41379 0.034555
3.5862  0.41379 0.22325
3.7241  0.41379 0.26337
3.8621  0.41379 0.048114
4   0.41379 0.2468

0   0.44828 0.22762
0.13793 0.44828 0.022815
0.27586 0.44828 0.1838
0.41379 0.44828 0.21174
0.55172 0.44828 0.07372
0.68966 0.44828 0.10663
0.82759 0.44828 0.20915
0.96552 0.44828 0.18507
1.1034  0.44828 0.063306
1.2414  0.44828 0.084613
1.3793  0.44828 0.18763
1.5172  0.44828 0.20603
1.6552  0.44828 0.14038
1.7931  0.44828 0.02356
1.931   0.44828 0.098173
2.069   0.44828 0.18312
2.2069  0.44828 0.20716
2.3448  0.44828 0.16774
2.4828  0.44828 0.081009
2.6207  0.44828 0.0258
2.7586  0.44828 0.12344
2.8966  0.44828 0.18839
3.0345  0.44828 0.20755
3.1724  0.44828 0.18
3.3103  0.44828 0.11162
3.4483  0.44828 0.029009
3.5862  0.44828 0.18689
3.7241  0.44828 0.22044
3.8621  0.44828 0.040304
4   0.44828 0.20644

0   0.48276 0.18273
0.13793 0.48276 0.018319
0.27586 0.48276 0.14756
0.41379 0.48276 0.17002
0.55172 0.48276 0.059255
0.68966 0.48276 0.085517
0.82759 0.48276 0.16783
0.96552 0.48276 0.14854
1.1034  0.48276 0.050826
1.2414  0.48276 0.067902
1.3793  0.48276 0.1506
1.5172  0.48276 0.16538
1.6552  0.48276 0.1127
1.7931  0.48276 0.018925
1.931   0.48276 0.078795
2.069   0.48276 0.14699
2.2069  0.48276 0.16628
2.3448  0.48276 0.13463
2.4828  0.48276 0.065007
2.6207  0.48276 0.020724
2.7586  0.48276 0.099085
2.8966  0.48276 0.15119
3.0345  0.48276 0.16655
3.1724  0.48276 0.1444
3.3103  0.48276 0.089509
3.4483  0.48276 0.023387
3.5862  0.48276 0.15009
3.7241  0.48276 0.177
3.8621  0.48276 0.032432
4   0.48276 0.16552

0   0.51724 0.13788
0.13793 0.51724 0.013837
0.27586 0.51724 0.11132
0.41379 0.51724 0.1283
0.55172 0.51724 0.044785
0.68966 0.51724 0.064425
0.82759 0.51724 0.12655
0.96552 0.51724 0.11204
1.1034  0.51724 0.038356
1.2414  0.51724 0.051199
1.3793  0.51724 0.11359
1.5172  0.51724 0.12476
1.6552  0.51724 0.085027
1.7931  0.51724 0.014293
1.931   0.51724 0.05943
2.069   0.51724 0.11088
2.2069  0.51724 0.12543
2.3448  0.51724 0.10154
2.4828  0.51724 0.049015
2.6207  0.51724 0.015651
2.7586  0.51724 0.074743
2.8966  0.51724 0.11402
3.0345  0.51724 0.12557
3.1724  0.51724 0.10884
3.3103  0.51724 0.067421
3.4483  0.51724 0.017758
3.5862  0.51724 0.1133
3.7241  0.51724 0.13358
3.8621  0.51724 0.024576
4   0.51724 0.12458

0   0.55172 0.09362
0.13793 0.55172 0.0094225
0.27586 0.55172 0.075543
0.41379 0.55172 0.087115
0.55172 0.55172 0.030488
0.68966 0.55172 0.043614
0.82759 0.55172 0.085798
0.96552 0.55172 0.076002
1.1034  0.55172 0.026048
1.2414  0.55172 0.034709
1.3793  0.55172 0.077058
1.5172  0.55172 0.084658
1.6552  0.55172 0.057712
1.7931  0.55172 0.0097188
1.931   0.55172 0.040312
2.069   0.55172 0.075223
2.2069  0.55172 0.085091
2.3448  0.55172 0.068875
2.4828  0.55172 0.033226
2.6207  0.55172 0.010644
2.7586  0.55172 0.050712
2.8966  0.55172 0.07732
3.0345  0.55172 0.085112
3.1724  0.55172 0.073727
3.3103  0.55172 0.045613
3.4483  0.55172 0.012191
3.5862  0.55172 0.076966
3.7241  0.55172 0.090701
3.8621  0.55172 0.016814
4   0.55172 0.084173

0   0.58621 0.050466
0.13793 0.58621 0.0051224
0.27586 0.58621 0.040648
0.41379 0.58621 0.046945
0.55172 0.58621 0.016538
0.68966 0.58621 0.023332
0.82759 0.58621 0.046073
0.96552 0.58621 0.040873
1.1034  0.58621 0.01405
1.2414  0.58621 0.018629
1.3793  0.58621 0.041435
1.5172  0.58621 0.045556
1.6552  0.58621 0.031078
1.7931  0.58621 0.0052589
1.931   0.58621 0.021672
2.069   0.58621 0.040461
2.2069  0.58621 0.045763
2.3448  0.58621 0.037022
2.4828  0.58621 0.01783
2.6207  0.58621 0.0057627
2.7586  0.58621 0.027282
2.8966  0.58621 0.041537
3.0345  0.58621 0.045667
3.1724  0.58621 0.039497
3.3103  0.58621 0.024353
3.4483  0.58621 0.0067561
3.5862  0.58621 0.041528
3.7241  0.58621 0.04888
3.8621  0.58621 0.0092251
4   0.58621 0.044831

0   0.62069 0.0089521
0.13793 0.62069 0.0009935
0.27586 0.62069 0.0070706
0.41379 0.62069 0.0082975
0.55172 0.62069 0.0031284
0.68966 0.62069 0.0038208
0.82759 0.62069 0.0078554
0.96552 0.62069 0.0070818
1.1034  0.62069 0.0025173
1.2414  0.62069 0.0031554
1.3793  0.62069 0.0071654
1.5172  0.62069 0.0079451
1.6552  0.62069 0.0054638
1.7931  0.62069 0.0009727
1.931   0.62069 0.0037429
2.069   0.62069 0.0070261
2.2069  0.62069 0.0079351
2.3448  0.62069 0.0063806
2.4828  0.62069 0.0030171
2.6207  0.62069 0.0010771
2.7586  0.62069 0.004749
2.8966  0.62069 0.0071186
3.0345  0.62069 0.0077207
3.1724  0.62069 0.0065645
3.3103  0.62069 0.003908
3.4483  0.62069 0.0015542
3.5862  0.62069 0.0074328
3.7241  0.62069 0.0086322
3.8621  0.62069 0.0019302
4   0.62069 0.0070515

0   0.65517 0.030573
0.13793 0.65517 0.0029689
0.27586 0.65517 0.024857
0.41379 0.65517 0.028483
0.55172 0.65517 0.0096965
0.68966 0.65517 0.014693
0.82759 0.65517 0.028447
0.96552 0.65517 0.025037
1.1034  0.65517 0.008464
1.2414  0.65517 0.01154
1.3793  0.65517 0.025406
1.5172  0.65517 0.027815
1.6552  0.65517 0.018901
1.7931  0.65517 0.0031174
1.931   0.65517 0.013295
2.069   0.65517 0.024755
2.2069  0.65517 0.028019
2.3448  0.65517 0.022735
2.4828  0.65517 0.01105
2.6207  0.65517 0.0033982
2.7586  0.65517 0.016669
2.8966  0.65517 0.025576
3.0345  0.65517 0.028308
3.1724  0.65517 0.024691
3.3103  0.65517 0.015481
3.4483  0.65517 0.0035406
3.5862  0.65517 0.025047
3.7241  0.65517 0.029689
3.8621  0.65517 0.0051848
4   0.65517 0.02873

0   0.68966 0.067511
0.13793 0.68966 0.0066614
0.27586 0.68966 0.054699
0.41379 0.68966 0.062848
0.55172 0.68966 0.021648
0.68966 0.68966 0.032008
0.82759 0.68966 0.062389
0.96552 0.68966 0.055055
1.1034  0.68966 0.018714
1.2414  0.68966 0.025286
1.3793  0.68966 0.055854
1.5172  0.68966 0.061236
1.6552  0.68966 0.041665
1.7931  0.68966 0.0069314
1.931   0.68966 0.029222
2.069   0.68966 0.05446
2.2069  0.68966 0.061627
2.3448  0.68966 0.049957
2.4828  0.68966 0.024209
2.6207  0.68966 0.0075652
2.7586  0.68966 0.036686
2.8966  0.68966 0.056147
3.0345  0.68966 0.062006
3.1724  0.68966 0.05393
3.3103  0.68966 0.033625
3.4483  0.68966 0.0082175
3.5862  0.68966 0.055392
3.7241  0.68966 0.065514
3.8621  0.68966 0.01179
4   0.68966 0.062084

0   0.72414 0.10153
0.13793 0.72414 0.010073
0.27586 0.72414 0.08216
0.41379 0.72414 0.09448
0.55172 0.72414 0.032658
0.68966 0.72414 0.047933
0.82759 0.72414 0.093617
0.96552 0.72414 0.082677
1.1034  0.72414 0.028146
1.2414  0.72414 0.037936
1.3793  0.72414 0.083876
1.5172  0.72414 0.091993
1.6552  0.72414 0.062616
1.7931  0.72414 0.010443
1.931   0.72414 0.04388
2.069   0.72414 0.081799
2.2069  0.72414 0.092558
2.3448  0.72414 0.07501
2.4828  0.72414 0.036319
2.6207  0.72414 0.011401
2.7586  0.72414 0.055109
2.8966  0.72414 0.084282
3.0345  0.72414 0.093019
3.1724  0.72414 0.080834
3.3103  0.72414 0.050326
3.4483  0.72414 0.012544
3.5862  0.72414 0.083335
3.7241  0.72414 0.098509
3.8621  0.72414 0.017925
4   0.72414 0.092667

0   0.75862 0.13227
0.13793 0.75862 0.01317
0.27586 0.75862 0.10694
0.41379 0.75862 0.12303
0.55172 0.75862 0.042602
0.68966 0.75862 0.062297
0.82759 0.75862 0.12179
0.96552 0.75862 0.1076
1.1034  0.75862 0.036657
1.2414  0.75862 0.049347
1.3793  0.75862 0.10915
1.5172  0.75862 0.11974
1.6552  0.75862 0.081516
1.7931  0.75862 0.013612
1.931   0.75862 0.057099
2.069   0.75862 0.10645
2.2069  0.75862 0.12045
2.3448  0.75862 0.097604
2.4828  0.75862 0.047241
2.6207  0.75862 0.014859
2.7586  0.75862 0.07172
2.8966  0.75862 0.10965
3.0345  0.75862 0.12098
3.1724  0.75862 0.10509
3.3103  0.75862 0.065357
3.4483  0.75862 0.016466
3.5862  0.75862 0.10857
3.7241  0.75862 0.12831
3.8621  0.75862 0.023509
4   0.75862 0.12018

0   0.7931  0.15942
0.13793 0.7931  0.015917
0.27586 0.7931  0.12881
0.41379 0.7931  0.14823
0.55172 0.7931  0.051382
0.68966 0.7931  0.074966
0.82759 0.7931  0.14665
0.96552 0.7931  0.12959
1.1034  0.7931  0.044167
1.2414  0.7931  0.059416
1.3793  0.7931  0.13146
1.5172  0.7931  0.14423
1.6552  0.7931  0.098195
1.7931  0.7931  0.016409
1.931   0.7931  0.068764
2.069   0.7931  0.12821
2.2069  0.7931  0.14507
2.3448  0.7931  0.11754
2.4828  0.7931  0.056881
2.6207  0.7931  0.017911
2.7586  0.7931  0.08638
2.8966  0.7931  0.13204
3.0345  0.7931  0.14565
3.1724  0.7931  0.12649
3.3103  0.7931  0.078634
3.4483  0.7931  0.019937
3.5862  0.7931  0.13085
3.7241  0.7931  0.15463
3.8621  0.7931  0.02847
4   0.7931  0.14438

0   0.82759 0.18273
0.13793 0.82759 0.01829
0.27586 0.82759 0.14754
0.41379 0.82759 0.16982
0.55172 0.82759 0.058912
0.68966 0.82759 0.085817
0.82759 0.82759 0.16794
0.96552 0.82759 0.14843
1.1034  0.82759 0.050601
1.2414  0.82759 0.068042
1.3793  0.82759 0.15057
1.5172  0.82759 0.1652
1.6552  0.82759 0.11248
1.7931  0.82759 0.018807
1.931   0.82759 0.078755
2.069   0.82759 0.14685
2.2069  0.82759 0.16616
2.3448  0.82759 0.13462
2.4828  0.82759 0.065137
2.6207  0.82759 0.020523
2.7586  0.82759 0.098933
2.8966  0.82759 0.15121
3.0345  0.82759 0.16678
3.1724  0.82759 0.14482
3.3103  0.82759 0.089985
3.4483  0.82759 0.022926
3.5862  0.82759 0.14996
3.7241  0.82759 0.1772
3.8621  0.82759 0.032747
4   0.82759 0.16508

0   0.86207 0.202
0.13793 0.86207 0.020262
0.27586 0.86207 0.16299
0.41379 0.86207 0.18765
0.55172 0.86207 0.065129
0.68966 0.86207 0.094769
0.82759 0.86207 0.18552
0.96552 0.86207 0.16397
1.1034  0.86207 0.055911
1.2414  0.86207 0.075161
1.3793  0.86207 0.16634
1.5172  0.86207 0.18251
1.6552  0.86207 0.12428
1.7931  0.86207 0.020786
1.931   0.86207 0.087
2.069   0.86207 0.16223
2.2069  0.86207 0.18356
2.3448  0.86207 0.14872
2.4828  0.86207 0.071952
2.6207  0.86207 0.022679
2.7586  0.86207 0.10929
2.8966  0.86207 0.16703
3.0345  0.86207 0.18422
3.1724  0.86207 0.15994
3.3103  0.86207 0.099364
3.4483  0.86207 0.025401
3.5862  0.86207 0.16574
3.7241  0.86207 0.19584
3.8621  0.86207 0.036289
4   0.86207 0.18215

0   0.89655 0.21709
0.13793 0.89655 0.021817
0.27586 0.89655 0.17506
0.41379 0.89655 0.20156
0.55172 0.89655 0.069987
0.68966 0.89655 0.10175
0.82759 0.89655 0.19923
0.96552 0.89655 0.17611
1.1034  0.89655 0.060057
1.2414  0.89655 0.080714
1.3793  0.89655 0.17865
1.5172  0.89655 0.19602
1.6552  0.89655 0.13348
1.7931  0.89655 0.022332
1.931   0.89655 0.093431
2.069   0.89655 0.17423
2.2069  0.89655 0.19713
2.3448  0.89655 0.15971
2.4828  0.89655 0.077268
2.6207  0.89655 0.024359
2.7586  0.89655 0.11737
2.8966  0.89655 0.17937
3.0345  0.89655 0.19782
3.1724  0.89655 0.17173
3.3103  0.89655 0.10666
3.4483  0.89655 0.027345
3.5862  0.89655 0.17806
3.7241  0.89655 0.2104
3.8621  0.89655 0.03906
4   0.89655 0.1955

0   0.93103 0.22792
0.13793 0.93103 0.022941
0.27586 0.93103 0.18368
0.41379 0.93103 0.21151
0.55172 0.93103 0.073462
0.68966 0.93103 0.10674
0.82759 0.93103 0.20903
0.96552 0.93103 0.18477
1.1034  0.93103 0.06302
1.2414  0.93103 0.084678
1.3793  0.93103 0.18743
1.5172  0.93103 0.20566
1.6552  0.93103 0.14005
1.7931  0.93103 0.023438
1.931   0.93103 0.09802
2.069   0.93103 0.18279
2.2069  0.93103 0.20682
2.3448  0.93103 0.16756
2.4828  0.93103 0.081063
2.6207  0.93103 0.025557
2.7586  0.93103 0.12314
2.8966  0.93103 0.18817
3.0345  0.93103 0.20752
3.1724  0.93103 0.18014
3.3103  0.93103 0.11184
3.4483  0.93103 0.028749
3.5862  0.93103 0.18688
3.7241  0.93103 0.22081
3.8621  0.93103 0.041038
4   0.93103 0.20511

0   0.96552 0.23449
0.13793 0.96552 0.023627
0.27586 0.96552 0.18885
0.41379 0.96552 0.21748
0.55172 0.96552 0.075552
0.68966 0.96552 0.10973
0.82759 0.96552 0.2149
0.96552 0.96552 0.18997
1.1034  0.96552 0.064799
1.2414  0.96552 0.08705
1.3793  0.96552 0.19269
1.5172  0.96552 0.21144
1.6552  0.96552 0.14399
1.7931  0.96552 0.024101
1.931   0.96552 0.10076
2.069   0.96552 0.18791
2.2069  0.96552 0.21262
2.3448  0.96552 0.17226
2.4828  0.96552 0.083334
2.6207  0.96552 0.026272
2.7586  0.96552 0.12658
2.8966  0.96552 0.19343
3.0345  0.96552 0.21332
3.1724  0.96552 0.18517
3.3103  0.96552 0.11492
3.4483  0.96552 0.029608
3.5862  0.96552 0.19218
3.7241  0.96552 0.22705
3.8621  0.96552 0.042218
4   0.96552 0.21099

0   1   0.2297
0.13793 1   0.023967
0.27586 1   0.1906
0.41379 1   0.21952
0.55172 1   0.076268
0.68966 1   0.11074
0.82759 1   0.21689
0.96552 1   0.19174
1.1034  1   0.065403
1.2414  1   0.087853
1.3793  1   0.19447
1.5172  1   0.21339
1.6552  1   0.14532
1.7931  1   0.024326
1.931   1   0.10169
2.069   1   0.18964
2.2069  1   0.21457
2.3448  1   0.17384
2.4828  1   0.084098
2.6207  1   0.026512
2.7586  1   0.12774
2.8966  1   0.1952
3.0345  1   0.21527
3.1724  1   0.18685
3.3103  1   0.11596
3.4483  1   0.029907
3.5862  1   0.19399
3.7241  1   0.22919
3.8621  1   0.042614
4   1   0.21101
```

Comment: `axis on top`? might help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `axis on top` to the `axis` options